# Can I get cheap JSP/ JSF hosting in shared hosting plans?

Tags: java, jsp, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I want to use JSF with Facelets/JSP in my website. Can I get Java hosting in cheap shared hosting plans ?

Comment: Sorry this question is off-topic, although it's a good one. Try it on the webmaster forum. Personnaly, I recommand 4java.ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are asking about shared hosting because you actually want shared hosting or because of the expense typically associated with a VPS. If you are looking for a good, inexpensive VPS, check out Quality Servers. I opened an account with them about a month ago and couldn't be happier. Their prices are dirt cheap and you have full control over your server. I got to them via this link: http://www.lowendbox.com/blog/qualityservers-4-600mb-openvz-vps-in-us-or-uk/, which from what I can tell will get you a cheaper price than shopping from the main page of the site.

Comment: If you use a VPS for Java, though, make sure you do not get an OpenVZ one (or Virtuoso). Xen and the like are fine, though. OpenVZ doesn't play well with the way Java reserves virtual memory (even if it doesn't use it).

Comment: @Luke & Paul: Thank you both! Could you please also give me an idea like around how much does a VPS cost. I did check with some hosting companies as well. They sell it for 15$/ month while shared hosting for 9$/month. I just need to know whether there are any other kind of charges in VPS which are not in shared hosting. Just trying to figure out that how much more costlier a VPS would be than a shared hosting  for my  client.

Comment: The cost is about $6.50 USD/month. However, as Paul pointed out, OpenVZ doesn't play nice with Java VM. I didn't know this when I originally answered because I'm not a Java dev. They do have Xen VPSs, I just can't speak for them and they aren't as cheap as OpenVZ.

FYI, I'm currently running about 6 or 7 sites (all PHP including 3 Wordpress installations). I'm only getting a 5-6K hits a month combined, so the specs suit me perfectly. It ends up being a few bucks cheaper than my old shared hosting provider and I don't have to worry about competing for resources on an overloaded shared server.